# How to change IPython shell text literal color (Windows Powershell)

Tags: powershell, ipython

#### Problem definition

I use IPython on Windows Powershell. For some reason the color of string literals is unreadably dark red:

[image: Ipython in powershell]

For comparison, here is how it looks on VSCode, using powershell "shell" and Ipython:

[image: Ipython in powershell in VSCode]

#### Question

IPython certainly uses some commands to tell the shell the color to be used. How can I modify the string literal color to be lighter red? I would like this to be computer-wide (or at least user-wide) setting.

Comment: Maybe by setting the `InteractiveShell.colors` to `"linux"` helps? [Terminal Colors](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#terminal-colors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to set individual colors. In `ipython_config.py` (see other answer if you don't know how to get there), you will find a commented entry `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides`.
Uncomment that entry and set a color for the String token to your liking:

```
## Override highlighting format for specific tokens
from pygments.token import Token
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {Token.String: '#009999'}
```

This makes strings readable again!

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did to make the text more readable. Thanks for SO users [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599884/christoph) for pointing me to right direction.

#### 1. Checked that I do not have any configuration files in `~\.ipython`

- On windows `~` translated into `C:\Users\<USER>\`.

#### 2. Ran `ipython profile create`

- The output was

```
PS C:\Somefolder> ipython profile create
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: 'C:\\Users\\<USER>\\.ipython\\profile_default\\ipython_config.py'
```

#### 3. Edited the `ipython_config.py`

- Edited the following line:

```
#c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {}
```

into

```
from pygments.token import Token
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {Token.String: '#ff0000'}
```

### Results

[image]

### Other tokens

- From [pygments.token](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/default/pygments/token.py)

```
Token.Comment
Token.Error
Token.Escape
Token.Generic
Token.Keyword
Token.Literal
Token.Name
Token.Number
Token.Operator
Token.Other
Token.OutPrompt
Token.OutPromptNum
Token.Prompt
Token.PromptNum
Token.Punctuation
Token.String
Token.Text
Token.Token
```

### Available colors in PowerShell:

From left to right in the figure (with my own naming)

```
- Black #000000
- Middle blue #000080
- Green #008000
- Teal #008080
- Dark red #800000
- Dark blue #012456
- Light grey #eeedf0
- Grey #c0c0c0
- Dark grey #808080
- Bright blue #0000ff
- Bright light green #00ff00
- Bright light teal #00ffff
- Bright red #ff0000
- Pink #ff00ff
- Yellow #ffff00
- White #ffffff
```

[image: Powershell options (colors)]

Comment: This is quite annoying, you can choose if you don't want to be able to read strings or some keywords :-/
Somewhat related issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9723

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I made my answer more complete. Now there is a way to fully customize the colors. Seems that at least the Windows Powershell is quite limited to what comes into colors (some colors do not work at all; they are not understood and will be painted as grey..).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

On Win 10, Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 - I faced issues when using IPython with Powershell *- where Windows would change the color of certain Python keywords (e.g. self) to match the background color making it impossible to read.*

This obviously made using IPython difficult because keywords would show as I typed, but when I finished the word - it would change color and be hidden, although editable.

**The fix, related to solutions to this problem, was to:**

**1-** find the IPython configuration (~/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py - or wherever you are storing your ipython profile if you have changed path)

**2-** confirm my machine supports TRUECOLOR (instructions are in ipython_config.py)

**3 -** uncomment this line.

```
*c.TerminalInteractiveShell.true_color = True*
```

**4-** restart IPython terminal

Answer (score 0):

Locate your `ipython_config.py` profile in the .ipython directory using `ipython locate`.

If you don't have a profile, create one by running `ipython profile create`.

Open the `ipython_config.py` file in an editor and find the `# c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style = traitlets.Undefined` line.

Remove the comment and change the `taitlets.Undefined` bit into a string like `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style = "fruity"`.

Save and reload ipython.

You can find all the options for highlighting_style by running `pygmentize -L styles` in a terminal.