# Change the highlight color of the traceback in IPython Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, ipython

As shown in the image below, the background and foreground colors make it difficult to read the important part of the traceback output.

[image: bad highlight color]

My `ipython_config.py` is untouched. The only change I made to Powershell was to set the console's background color to black.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55586474/18758987), I set this in my `ipython_config.py`

```
from pygments.token import Token
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {Token.Error: '#012456'}
```

but it had no effect. So I reset it to the default empty dict for now.

I'm willing to use any color scheme which colors and highlights input and output text in a readable way.

Comment: I've struggled with colors on the black powershell terminal, and usually just resort to `%colors nocolor`. Or use `qtconsole` which defaults to a white background.

Comment: the solution I went with was to inherit an old macbook :-]